# Handle onfocus event in Razor Pages

Tags: razor-pages, blazor-server-side

I have rows of `<textarea />`s and want to handle the `onfocus` and `onblur` events and pass along the row data. Cannot get it to work at all.

```html
<div>
  @foreach (Person p in People){
    <textarea rows="4" onfocus="@hasFocus(p)" onblur="@lostFocus(p)">p.Name</textarea>
  }
</div>
```

```cs
  public void hasFocus(Person p) {
    ...
  }
```

The events are not triggering.

Comment: I think the confusion here is because the syntax used to be `onfocus="@functionname()"` earlier in Blazor's life, so you are probably looking at outdated documentation. The final version of blazor has the @ in front, as shown in the answers below. `@onfocus="functionname()"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```cs
<div>
  @foreach (Person p in People){
    <textarea rows="4" 
      @onfocus="@( () => hasFocus(p) )" 
      @onblur="@( () => lostFocus(p) )">
        p.Name
    </textarea>
  }
</div>
```

According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#event-handling), the event attribute name is @on{eventname}.
Then use a lambda to pass your person parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Use @onfocus and @onblur

```
<textarea rows="4" @onfocus="hasFocus" @onblur="lostFocus">p.Name</textarea>
```

and

```
public void hasFocus(FocusEventArgs args)
{
}

public void lostFocus(FocusEventArgs args)
{
}
```

If you use only onfocus it will be an html attribute and not an eventlistener.

To pass your person object you need an action like this

```
 @onfocus="(args) => hasFocus(p)"
```